# How to checkout from chosen revision in git svn?

Tags: git, svn

I have a very big and old project - with hundreds commits every week. how to checkout it from chosen revision and make git index it only from that revision?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**. Git has no concept of partial checkouts (I guess you mean: only versions 10000 to now and ignore what's before 10000)

If you feel the project is too big you should consider breaking it up into smaller [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) (referenced repositories in SVN).

Git is very good in compressing and re-using deltas, so checking out even a very big project is not that big of a deal. It mostly comes down to file size.
If you look at the Linux Kernel - all revisions are almost constant in checkout time, mostly limited by your disk speed. While the whole repository is only 2-3 times the size of a checked out working copy.

Just have a look at the Kernel project and you will see - Git was specifically built for extremely large projects!

Comment: the problem is that i want to use git svn and I have used it before on small project and it took a lot of time to init it. plus i don't control the svn.

Comment: plus i don't know if git svn will work as well here and i just want to try it out.

Comment: The git svn init is run only once - sou you could just let it run over night and then it should be fine.

Comment: the problem is that its very slow, it might take a couple of days. i used it on small project and it took all nigth to index it.

Comment: You might want to look at the git svn init documentation to maybe limit the indexing to only a part of the svn project